# Error : queue.task_done() Called To Many Times In Python

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I'm Stuck On This For A While Now

```
class ThreadingPower(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self, queue):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.queue= queue

def run(self):
    while True:
        Manager = self.queue.get()
        for Numbers,HWID in Manager:
            r = requests.post(URL, data=payload) # License Checker Required Numbers ( Buyer Code ) And HWID ( License Code )
            data = (r.text)
            if ('Verified' in data):
                with open(resultsFile,'a+') as results: 
                    results.write("The Number : "+str(Numbers)+" Is Verified By The "+str(HWID))
                results.close()
                print str(HWID)+" Is Server Verified"
                active =+ 1
                self.queue.task_done()
            else:
                print str(HWID)+" Is Not Server Verified"
                self.queue.task_done()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(10):
        t = ThreadingPower(queue)
        t.setDaemon(False)
        t.start()

    queue.put(credentials)
    queue.join()
```

The Credentials Are Like This :

```
[
 ['UniqueHWID', 'BuyerCode'], 
 ['UniqueHWID', 'BuyerCode'], 
 ['UniqueHWID', 'BuyerCode']
]
```

It Kept Getting To Many Call Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: Error : queue.task_done() Called To Many Times

The call to `.task_done()` should be in sync with `.queue.get()`.
You do `.task_done()`, within the `for ...` loop many times.

Change your code to:

```
while True:
    Manager = self.queue.get()
    for Numbers,HWID in Manager:
        ...
        if ('Verified' in data):
            ...
            active =+ 1
        else:
            print str(HWID)+" Is Not Server Verified"

    self.queue.task_done()
```

Comment: Thank You So Much